# Connection Refused using PHPMailer with Namecheap Accounts

Tags: php, phpmailer, namecheap

I have been using the code below to try to send emails out to people who sign up on my website however I can not get the code to work with my namecheap hosted email account. This [namecheap email configuration](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1179/2175/general-configuration-for-mail-clients-and-mobile-devices) was used but it seems to still give me an error. I have tried the same code with the hotmail settings and it works just fine.

**Error**

```
2016-06-17 09:28:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (61) 2016-06-17 09:28:33    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

**Code**

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    function sendmail($host, $username, $password, $to, $subject, $message, $fromName, $toName, $port, $debug) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $body = $message;
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = $host;
        if ($debug) $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
        $mail->Port = $port;
        $mail->Username = $username;
        $mail->Password = $password;
        $mail->SetFrom($to, $name);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($to, $name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody = $message;
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);

        $address = $to;
        $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
        if($mail->Send()) {
            echo "Message sent";
        } else {
            echo "Mailer: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }

echo sendMail("mail.privateemail.com", "noreply@example.com", "password", "recipient@example.com", "Subject", "Message", "Name", "Sender Name", 25, true);
```

Comment: You're not doing anything particularly wrong, but I can see that you've based your code on an old example, so make sure you're using [latest versions](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It does sound like your ISP is blocking your outbound connection. They probably require you to relay through their own servers. This is all covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

After talking to support it seems that there was some issues going on with their private email servers and the following message was displayed on the Namecheap accounts page:

> Dear Private Email users, 
>   We are glad to let you know that the issues with Mailboxes Management functionality of Private Email section in Namecheap account have been fixed. 
>   Also, please be aware that non-secured ports (143, 110, 25, 587) are available and fully functional now. Please feel free to use them while setting up an email client. 
>   Should you have any questions feel free to contact our Support Team.

I have gone through each port and found **587** to work for me