# Send Nodemailer e-mail with Namecheap email

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, namecheap

I have been successful connecting a Gmail account with Xoauth, but I recently acquired a Namecheap privateemail account and can't for the life of me figure out how to set it up. This is the code that I have:

```
var smtp = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.privateemail.com',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: 'contact@myemail.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877979/connection-refused-using-phpmailer-with-namecheap-accounts) and tried all the other port numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be secured connection in that case the port should be 465

> 465 port for SSL, 25 or 26 for TLS/STARTTLS

Answer (score 0):

According to Namecheap support website as of Nov 7, 2017 - 
configuration to send messages through Namecheap Private Email server:

```
Outgoing server (SMTP): port 465 for SSL, port 587 for TLS/STARTTLS

Outgoing server authentication should be switched on,
SPA (secure password authentication) must be disabled.
```

Comment: Oh and, outgoing server name to use: mail.privateemail.com. BTW, TLS/STARTTLS is secure.

Comment: If the flag `secure` is set `True`, then you need to use 465, otherwise you get error `Error: 8541117952:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:`